# Protractor - describe is not defined

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I am using protractor js for testing. When i try to run the test case using

> protractor e2e/main/test.spec.js

My conf.js

```
// An example configuration file.
 exports.config = {
// The address of a running selenium server.
 seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000',

capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
  args: ['--test-type']
  }
},

// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
// protractor is called.
 specs: ['*_spec.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
 showColors: true,
 defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
};
```

I got reference error

```
> D:\cronj\gxp\10-09-2014\e2e\main\test.spec.js:3
describe('Login page', function() {
^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\cronj\gxp\10-09-2014\e2e\main\test.spec.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\Cronj4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\lib\configParser.js:171:20)
    at Object.init (C:\Users\Cronj4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
lib\launcher.js:30:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cronj4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot
ractor\lib\cli.js:129:23)
```

Could any one help to run the test case using protractor?

Comment: could you show your protractor configuration file ?

Comment: @Maxdow, i have added my configuration file. Please take a look.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should launch your config file instead of your spec file .

```
protractor protractor.config.js
```

In the config file, the "specs" attribute is a glob pattern array that will inject your spec files within the test environment, with the correct definition for objets like "describe" or "it".

Comment: When i run protractor e2e/main/protractor.conf.js i got C:\Users\Cronj4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\seleniu
m-webdriver\http\index.js:136
      callback(new Error(message));

Comment: anyway, Maxdow is right, you have to use your config spec as parameter. did you start selenium via `webdriver-manager start`?

Comment: yeah, i have to install java

Comment: indeed you need java because protractor is built on selenium's webdriver which use java ;)

Comment: when I try debug this I get this undefined error, I debug the lib/cli file and pass in the spec file by itself