# Protractor typescript: Sudden error with ts case mean I can't compile to run test as js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, automation, protractor

I am a novice with Protractor typescript and I am having a real headache compiling at test file.

[Watch the video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrrkkhk0io02dtk/Error%20in%20locator%20script.mp4?dl=0)

As you can see the code there is an error  (error TS2582):in the .ts test case (that wasn't there before, I'm certain).

How do I fix that so I can compile with tsc and successfully run my test case?

Here is the code:

```
ChaLoctestscript.ts:5:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest
` or `npm i @types/mocha`  and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.

5 describe('Using chain loctor',function(){
  ~~~~~~~~
ChaLoctestscript.ts:8:2 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `
npm i @types/mocha`  and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.

8  it('Opening google page',function(){
   ~~


Found 2 errors.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor - describe is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760870/protractor-describe-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this issue already existed.